App installed one year ago doesn't open anymore
A year ago I bought a DJI drone and installed the DJI Fly app on my Android 13. Note that this app is not available on Google app store. It can only be installed with an apk, downloaded from DJI website.
As it turned out, that specific version of the app was affected by a rather useful bug, which is not the topic of the discussion. Hence, I never updated the app.
A few days ago the app stopped working. When I tap the icon, there is a window opening, but it closes itself a moment later, without showing the app main screen. No error message is shown. It crossed my mind that exactly one year passed from the installation date, which leads me to believe in some planned obsolescence mechanism. So, I turned on Airplane mode and reopened the app: same behavior (note: so far, I was always able to open the app and fly the drone even when there was no cellular connectivity).
A few months ago a friend of mine also experienced something similar, although at that time I didn't realized that exactly one year passed by his original installation. Apparently, the only solution would be to update the app, thus losing the bugged capability.
Regardless of the lost capability, this was a wake up call to me in that I realized that I don't own the drone. If tomorrow DJI decides that my drone model must not fly, my days using the drone are going to be numbered, which makes me uncomfortable.
I have attempted to:

uninstall the app from the launcher, and reinstall it (the same version). The installation fails with the following message: app not installed as package appears to be invalid.
I have downloaded Android's platform tools. Then, I uninstalled it with adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 dji.go.v5 and reinstalled it with adb install path/to/apk. The installation is successful but the app doesn't work, with the same symptoms as mentioned above.

My questions are:

(not really important, but out of curiosity) from a developer standpoint, what mechanism could implement this planned obsolescence behavior? I believe there could be some files stored on the device, because the app won't start even when using Airplane mode.
I though uninstalling with adb was going to remove all data associated to a particular app. But since the app doesn't work after the new installation, this can't be right... What else can I attempt to get that specific version of the app working again?

Note: format the phone is the last thing I would want to try, as it would take me a few days to get it fully operational again. But if nothing comes to mind, I might be inclined to try...
EDIT: adding logcat about DJI application:
10-11 14:58:40.765  1394  2817 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=dji.go.v5/com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity bnds=[242,1001][441,1334]} from uid 10208
10-11 14:58:40.773  1394  1780 D ResourceManagerUtils: getPid: pid not found, processName=dji.go.v5
10-11 14:58:40.787  1394  1788 I ActivityManager: Start proc 22911:dji.go.v5/u0a33 for next-top-activity {dji.go.v5/com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity}
10-11 14:58:40.793  4724 12270 W SQLiteLog: (28) double-quoted string literal: "dji.go.v5"
10-11 14:58:40.796 22911 22911 I dji.go.v5: Using CollectorTypeCC GC.
10-11 14:58:40.797 22911 22911 E dji.go.v5: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
10-11 14:58:40.801     0     0 I KERNEL  : [17804.585782] (CPU:7-pid:22911:dji.go.v5) [14:58:40.800390703] binder: 22911:22911 ioctl 40046210 7fdf319310 returned -22
10-11 14:58:40.803  1394  5281 D CoreBackPreview: Window{b12c445 u0 Splash Screen dji.go.v5}: Setting back callback OnBackInvokedCallbackInfo{mCallback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@25f76a7, mPriority=0}
10-11 14:58:40.810  2504  2932 D GameGenieHandler: intent action: android.intent.action.MAIN className: com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity
10-11 14:58:40.810  2504  2941 I AppOpsStatusUpdateHandler: pkgName: dji.go.v5, reason: TopResumedActivityChanged, displayedTime: -5566, isExternalDisplay: false, 1stLaunchInMem: true, windowingMode: 1, from: com.teslacoilsw.launcher
10-11 14:58:40.812  2517  2517 V AsusFocusAppManager: Default display package: dji.go.v5, bounds: Rect(0, 0 - 2400, 1080)
10-11 14:58:40.812  2504  2504 D TaskWatcherSvc: pkgName: dji.go.v5 taskId: 400 game app:0
10-11 14:58:40.812  1394  1751 D NetworkManagement: Current focus uid is 10033 [dji.go.v5]
10-11 14:58:40.816  2517  2517 V EdgeFreeformShortcutTipManager: Top package name: com.teslacoilsw.launcher -> dji.go.v5
10-11 14:58:40.820 22911 22911 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-4 for other apk /system/framework/com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar. target_sdk_version=30, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/dji.go.v5
10-11 14:58:40.822 22911 22911 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-5 for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=30, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/dji.go.v5
10-11 14:58:40.824 22911 22911 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-6 for other apk /data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=30, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/dji.go.v5
10-11 14:58:40.829  2957 22925 D OpenedAppInfo_Launcher: onChange: dji.go.v5, previous: com.teslacoilsw.launcher
10-11 14:58:40.832 22911 22911 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'dji.go.v5' set to: 'default'
10-11 14:58:40.832 22911 22911 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE GameManagerService for dji.go.v5: false
10-11 14:58:40.837  2504  2504 D PwrSvrSvc: xProfile current package:dji.go.v5 act:com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity sMode:0 pMode:9 game:0
10-11 14:58:40.837  2504  2504 D PwrSvrSvc: current package: mPreTaskId:-1 taskId:400
10-11 14:58:40.841 22911 22911 D nativeloader: Load /data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/lib/arm64/libDexHelper.so using ns clns-6 from class loader (caller=/data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/base.apk): ok
10-11 14:58:41.078 22911 22911 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 22911 (dji.go.v5), pid 22911 (dji.go.v5)
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'asus/EU_I006D/ASUS_I006D:13/TKQ1.220807.001/33.0210.0210.332:user/release-keys'
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2024-10-11 14:58:41.139119818+0200
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 1s
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: dji.go.v5
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : pid: 22911, tid: 22911, name: dji.go.v5  >>> dji.go.v5 <<<
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : uid: 10033
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000597f  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007fdf317cc0
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x4  6d60421f5c646b68  x5  6d60421f5c646b68  x6  6d60421f5c646b68  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007ecd9cfc60  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000007ecda10ba8
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000007fdf3165d0  x13 0000000000000044  x14 0000007fdf317918  x15 0000000034155555
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007ecda78d70  x17 0000007ecda54830  x18 0000007ed9376000  x19 000000000000597f
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x20 000000000000597f  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000003  x23 0000000000000010
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x24 000000000000002a  x25 0000007ed8a1b000  x26 0000002900000000  x27 0000007ed8b5ccc1
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000007ed8b5ccad  x29 0000007fdf317d40
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000007ecda01ae4  sp  0000007fdf317ca0  pc  0000007ecda01b10  pst 0000000000001000
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000053b10  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168) (BuildId: b6e36868644c11f7ae60766bc6e49448)
10-11 14:58:41.514 22934 22934 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 000000000003069c  /data/app/~~Ol9m4Qcknqa3CzpjGr8dOw==/dji.go.v5-74p0HMHqEbgg7a7wCm1fzQ==/lib/arm64/libDexHelper.so
10-11 14:58:41.527  1394 22943 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity dji.go.v5/com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity
10-11 14:58:41.544  2517  2517 V EdgeFreeformShortcutTipManager: Top package name: dji.go.v5 -> com.teslacoilsw.launcher
10-11 14:58:41.544  2517  2517 V EdgeFreeformShortcutTipManager: Is ASUS launcher showing: false -> false
10-11 14:58:41.546     0     0 I KERNEL  : [17805.331749] (CPU:7-pid:4961:binder:1394_10) [14:58:41.546357005] [oem][alarm]alarmtimer_enqueue: comm:binder:1394_10 pid:4961 exp:69692692 func:timerfd_alarmproc
10-11 14:58:41.549  1394  2660 D CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
10-11 14:58:41.549  1394  2660 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 440
10-11 14:58:41.549  1394  2660 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
10-11 14:58:41.550     0     0 I KERNEL  : [17805.335825] (CPU:6-pid:14244:wk:binder_defe) [14:58:41.550433515] binder: undelivered transaction 6276565, process died.
10-11 14:58:41.550     0     0 I KERNEL  : [17805.335933] (CPU:6-pid:14244:wk:binder_defe) [14:58:41.550541484] binder: undelivered transaction 6276552, process died.
10-11 14:58:41.550  1394  5415 I ActivityManager: Process dji.go.v5 (pid 22911) has died: fg  TOP 
10-11 14:58:41.550  1394  5415 W ActivityManager: App Op allow to restart app, fg TOP 
10-11 14:58:41.550  1394  1841 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10033 pid 22911 in 0ms
10-11 14:58:41.550   922   922 I Zygote  : Process 22911 exited due to signal 6 (Aborted)
10-11 14:58:41.551  1394  5415 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_left_ActivityRecord{3ef108d u0 dji.go.v5/com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity} t400} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
10-11 14:58:41.551  1394  5415 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_top_ActivityRecord{3ef108d u0 dji.go.v5/com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity} t400} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
10-11 14:58:41.551  1394  5415 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_right_ActivityRecord{3ef108d u0 dji.go.v5/com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity} t400} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
10-11 14:58:41.551  1394  5415 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_bottom_ActivityRecord{3ef108d u0 dji.go.v5/com.dji.component.application.activity.DJIPureLaunchActivity} t400} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!


Unrelated to your questions, but try getting the logcat when the app closes by itself, it might tell the error/exception if the app actually crashes and closes.

When you installed the app one year ago was you phone already running Android 13?

@Robert yes. Only security patches were installed in the meantime. But the last one was several months ago.

Thanks @AndrewT. for the suggestion. I have updated the question with the logcat.

The logcat mentions the file /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so. apex is the "pony express" update system by Google where certain components of Android are directly updated by Play Store without the phone manufacturer involved. Thus one possible reason could be that Google updated this library and the new version is now incompatible with the app.
